# Why is this Azure DevOps pipeline release failing?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project that builds with no errors, but when it triggers the pipeline to release to Azure App Service, it fails with the following error:

> 2019-11-10T23:09:23.8008460Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip

What needs to be done to fix the release pipeline? The pipeline release is pulling the latest build as its artifact.

[image]

Comment: It's failing for exactly the reason the error message says: `No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip`. It can't find the file you're telling it to deploy. Validate that the file you're trying to push exists in your build artifacts and is downloaded to the location you're specifying.

Comment: Where do I find the build artifacts?

Comment: I strongly recommend starting by reading the documentation, which explains these concepts and guides you on how to navigate through the various sections to find things.

Comment: I have gone through a substantial amount of documentation, which has led me to ask this question here.

Comment: Did you add the Publish Build Artifacts task in your build pipeline? If yes, which parameter do you set in the Path to publish option? Which task do you use in your release pipeline? Could you please share a screenshot of the release pipeline task condition setting? If convenience, could you please share your release pipeline log here?

Comment: @crayden, hi, how the thing going? Does the below answer can fix your error? If yes, you can accept the answer, it will help other community user who get the same error. If not, you can free to leave your comment here or could you please provide the above information? : )

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT I answered the question below. Hope this helps others.

Comment: Glad you have the solution. You can convert it to answer and accept it. It will help other community users who have the same error. You can refer to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about how to accept the answer. Thanks. : )

Comment: Although many answers point to adding the artifact drop step in the build pipe, the way I solved this was to switch my release artifact default version from "Latest" to "Latest from the build pipeline default branch with tags"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline YAML was missing the following tasks. Not sure why this isn't included in the ASP.NET Core template, very confusing for developers new to Azure DevOps.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: It's pretty clear in the [Getting Started Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#package-and-deliver-your-code)

Comment: While this is an option, it begs the question of why the YAML didn't include that in the first place.  What I noticed is that the Default version selected in the Release Artifact was "Latest", and if I select "Latest from the build pipeline default branch with tags", then it is able to find the artifact from the build pipeline.  See my answer...

Answer (score 3):

### Assumptions

The following info assumes that you are appropriately [publishing your build artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) from your Build pipeline, and that you have added the correct build artifact into you release pipeline.

---

In your release pipeline you have specified a build artifact in the `Artifacts` area
[image]

When adding your build artifact to your release pipeline, you chose to give it an alias of `Build Artifact`. This means that at the very lease (with default settings) your `.zip` file will be in some sub-directory of `$(system.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/`

> A new unique folder in the agent is created for every release pipeline when you initiate a release, and the artifacts are downloaded into that folder. The $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) variable maps to this folder.

---

> To ensure the uniqueness of every artifact download, each artifact source linked to a release pipeline is automatically provided with a specific download location known as the source alias. This location can be accessed through the variable:
>
> `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\[source alias]`
>
> This uniqueness also ensures that, if you later rename a linked artifact source in its original location (for example, rename a build pipeline in Azure Pipelines or a project in Jenkins), you don't need to edit the task properties because the download location defined in the agent does not change.
>
> The source alias is, by default, the name of the source selected when you linked the artifact source, prefixed with an underscore; depending on the type of the artifact source this will be the name of the build pipeline, job, project, or repository. You can edit the source alias from the artifacts tab of a release pipeline; for example, when you change the name of the build pipeline and you want to use a source alias that reflects the name of the build pipeline.

(from some of the abundant [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#download)

Instead of searching for your package using `***.zip` (which isn't proper wildcard syntax) use `Build Artifact/**/*.zip`

- `**` is for recursively searching into directories

  - (I don't know what folder)
- `*` is for searching a part of a given level of the path

  - any file/folder that

    - starts with (`SomeFile.*`)
    - ends with (`*File.zip`)
    - and i think contains (`*meFi*`)

Answer (score 1):

When adding an Artifact of Source type "Build", select "Default version" as "Latest from the build pipeline default branch with tags", as follows:

[image]

Comment: The release pipeline would still require the build to publish an artifact. Build pipelines (last time I checked) don't do this automatically because there are quite a lot of usages for a build pipeline that do not (and even should not) produce an artifact.